# Обновление данных объекта в массиве

Tags: flutter, dart

В `Firestore` есть коллекция, в ней документ, в документе массив с объектами(Items). У каждого объекта есть данные. Как изменить данные определенного объекта?
Использую данную функцию

```
Future updateItem(Item item) async {
        categoryData.document(?).updateData({
          'ItemList':
              FieldValue.arrayUnion([item.toMap()])
        });
      }
```

Для данной функции требуется ID.  У объекта есть поле ID, но как передать этот ID в  `categoryData.document(?)`

[image: screen]

Comment: Вы перед тем как обновлять объект, его получили. Так возьмите от него id и передайте через параметр в функцию. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я скорей всего не правильно объяснил, добавил картинку базы. Если добавить categoryID  то он не изменяет , а добавляет объект. Если добавить productID то создается новый айди и пишет что документ с таким айди не найден.

Comment: а попробуйте использовать arrayRemove с categoryID , он удалит элемент? Если нет, то вы пытаетесь редактировать не то поле, либо передаете не правильный id...